# issues booting Ubuntu [Firmware Bug ] : ACPI _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, acpi

I am running into an issue booting Linux on a new machine.  I started with Ubuntu Server edition. I completed the initial setup via an ISO image, however when the machine restarted and went to load the fresh Ubuntu installation it stalled when trying to determine brightness. The last line in the boot process reads:

```
[Firmware Bug ] : ACPI: _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
```

Thinking that maybe this is a distro issue, I tried Fedora, same result.  Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with the firmware. If you know how to edit dsdt you will be able to fix it. If you are like me and can't edit dsdt, you will be stuck. I too have the same issue and read this article which explains how to fix it, but it's beyond the scope of my expertise. If anyone else can figure out an easier way I'd love to know.

http://cannibalcandy.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/dsdt-editing-put-an-end-to-your-acpi-woes/

Comment: Thanks, I intended to give that post a try but wasn't even able to boot gui-less to a terminal to edit.  I ended up returning the hardware (Lenovo H505s) and bought a couple PowerSpec that had 64bit Windows 7.